# Form submit button in table without function

Tags: laravel, forms, submit

Can anyone explains me, why the submit buttons no and yes in the following code not trigger?

Without the table, it works.

```
  <table class="table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th scope="col">Group</th>
            <th scope="col">Yes No</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      @foreach($invitations as $invitation) 
       {!! Form::open(array('route'=>'store.groupentry')) !!}  
        <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>
              Do you want to enter group {{$invitation->group_name}}?
           </td>
           <td>
              <input type="hidden" name="idgroup" value="{{ $invitation->idgroup }} "/>
              <input type="hidden" name="groupname" value="{{ $invitation->group_name }} "/>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name = "submitbutton" value = "save">Yes</button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name = "submitbutton" value = "nosave">No</button>
              {{ csrf_field() }}
            </td>
          </tr>
         </tbody>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
      @endforeach 
  </table>
```

Comment: Need the code of your Controller and the error output, what exactly does happen?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not valid html generation. You generate many forms wrap many tbody in one table. I think you need create one form, and before submit set hidden values with js